# Disable button refresh browers

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

I have a problem with sending message. I create a jsp page with calling form to send message using method Post. when i click button refresh on browers FF, it automatically send message again. I don't want to again send it. How could i disable button refresh?.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't.

Instead, use the [POST-Redirect-GET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern.

1. Let the form be POSTed to the form handler
2. Process the form data to send the message
3. Redirect to another URI
4. The browser will GET the other URI
5. If the browser is refreshed, the other URI will be requested with a GET, the form will not be resubmitted.

Comment: thanks it works. And now if i use ajax to send message with the same purpose. url_1---POST----url_2------url_1. when refresh page url_1, it also send agains message. how can i do in this situation?